# How store data in python's shelve module?

Tags: types, shelve

Im new at python, and i a little bit confused because of i can't change\store integer data in shelve db (of course not like key, just arg). Is it py(shelve) feature?

Testing code:

```
    import shelve

class User:
    def __init__(self, name = 'no name', user_id = '0', balance = 0):
        self.name = name
        self.user_id = user_id
        self.balance = balance
    def addUser(self, name, user_id):
        db = shelve.open('class_user')
        db[user_id] = User(name=name, user_id=user_id)
        db.close()
    def updateBalance(self, user_id, value):
        db = shelve.open('class_user')
        db[user_id].balance = value
        db.close()
    def printBalance(self, user_id):
        db = shelve.open('class_user')
        print(db[user_id].name, 'balance is', db[user_id].balance, sep=' ', end='!\n')
        db.close()
###################################################################

# test values
value = 1000
user_id = '1'
name = 'Mike'

User.printBalance(User, user_id=user_id)
User.updateBalance(User, user_id=user_id, value=value)
User.printBalance(User, user_id=user_id)
```

So should i use just string type or there is some what i doesn't still know?)  Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

For saving some data in shelve's database need to use *writeback* parameter. Like a:

```
def updateBalance(self, user_id, value):
    db = shelve.open('class_user', writeback=True)
    db[user_id].balance = value
    #db.sync() #excess cause of db.close()
    db.close()
```